# Jython (pass float array to java) is there more pythonic way?

Tags: jython

I am writing jython application with eclipse SWT/JFace. I have to pass float array to java object to get back some values from it. I am using jarray package for it. Is there more pythonic way to do it?

```
bounds = zeros(4, 'f')
# from java org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Path.getBounds(float[] bounds)
path.getBounds(bounds)
# from java org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle(int x, int y, int width,int height)
rect = Rectangle(int(round(bounds[0])), 
                     int(round(bounds[1])),
                     int(round(bounds[2])),
                     int(round(bounds[3])))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe. First, you can reduce the code a bit:

```
bounds = map(lambda v: int(round(v)), bounds)
```

This avoids the repeated cast. My next step would be to create a helper method to turn the array into `Rectangle`, so you don't have to repeat this code:

```
def toRectangle(bounds):
    bounds = map(lambda v: int(round(v)), bounds)
    return Rectangle(bounds[0], bounds[1], bounds[2], bounds[3])
```

That would leave you with:

```
rect = toRectangle(path.getBounds(zeroes(4, 'f'))
```

Alternatively, create a helper function that directly accepts the path.

Or you could monkey patch Path:

```
def helper(self):
    bounds = zeros(4, 'f')
    self.getBounds(bounds)
    bounds = map(lambda v: int(round(v)), bounds)
    return Rectangle(bounds[0], bounds[1], bounds[2], bounds[3])

org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Path.toRectangle = helper

rect = path.toRectangle()
```

Note that this might be slightly wrong. If it doesn't work, look at `classmethod()` and `new.instancemethod()` for how to add a method to a class on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

The use of list comprehensions is considered more pythonic these days:

```
rounded = [int(round(x)) for x in bounds]
```

This will give you a list of rounded ints.  Of course you could assign this to bounds instead of using "rounded"

```
bounds = [int(round(x)) for x in bounds]
```

And on our mailing list Charlie Groves pointed out that the whole thing can be exploded with the * operator like this:

```
rect = Rectangle(*[int(round(x)) for x in bounds])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's also worth pointing out that there's no need to use zeros to create an array.  You can just call getBounds with a Python iterable containing instances that can be converted to the proper type:

```
path.getBounds([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Well the problem is that void getBounds(float[] bounds) method (java native method of org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Path class) expects arrays of float numbers, return values are written to this array...

Comment: Ahh yes, if it's not returning the value, you're stuck with zeros.